# position not working in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have used s3 slider it is working fine in all browsers except safari. The first image is also not loaded properly in safari only.

http://www.bestandards.com/new/Joomla_tdavlin/. Is anyone can suggest me ?

```
  #header ul {
        display: block;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0 0 1px;
        padding: 10px 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        text-align: right;
        top: 0;
    }
.s3sliderImage {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: In my safari it is working properly. I cannot see a difference with chrome.

Comment: you mean the double 1st image?

Answer (score 2):

I can't really 100% check it, because it seem to only happen on the first page load but you can try removing `float: left;` and `position: relative;` from the class `.s3sliderImage` on line 2745, in `layout.css` but honestly in my opinion your main problem is that you have 2800 lines of css in just your layout css, and then you have 7 other huge css files for your site and your site is so simple it could be done with a lot less lines which will give it less chance to mess up and make it a lot easier to debug.